# How to iterate hash elements in groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash very similar to the following JSON object; This is only an example not the exact output.

I need to iterate over the hash and sort it by `host` or by `service_name` and then output in the view I am working with blocks reflecting those sorts.

If I go to my view expecting to see things listed by host, and I got ten services across that one host, I need to have a list on the view with that per host. Similarly, when it comes to `service_name`.

If I have 100 `service_names` matching, I need to block them and list them together.

I am new to Rails, and typically would handle this via JavaScript and JSON as what's being done is ultimately planned for heavy DOM manipulation anyway, but the lead guy insists this has to be done server-side first, so I am at a loss.

```
{
    "status": "successful",
    "service_list": [
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "oozie",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-namenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "single-database",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "datanode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "secondarynamenode",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "web",
            "status": "DEAD",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "tasktracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Service",
            "host": "1"
        },
        {
            "service_name": "jobtracker",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "status_message": "Running Master Service",
            "host": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In the future, strip your sample data down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem. It helps people who are answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code for grouping them by `service_name` with textual (not HTML) output. HTML would be the same, but with reasonable HTML markup. Service names are sorted alphabetically; no reason other than as an example.

```
svcs = val[:service_list]
puts "#{svcs.size} service entries."

grouped = svcs.group_by { |svc| svc[:service_name] }
puts "#{grouped.size} named services:"

grouped.keys.sort.each do |name|
    puts "  service: #{name}"
    grouped[name].each do |svc|
        puts "     host: #{svc[:host]}"
        puts "   status: #{svc[:status]}"
        puts "           #{svc[:status_message]}"
    end
    puts '-'*40
end
```

`group_by` returns a hash of arrays, keyed (in this case) by the `service_name` string (e.g., `"web"`, `"tasktracker"`, etc.) If you need to sort within each group's info, use `sort`. For example, to sort within each group by the `:status` value:

```
grouped.keys.sort.each do |name|
    puts "  service: #{name}"
    group_info = grouped[name]
    sorted_info = group_info.sort { |a, b| a[:status] <=> b[:status] }
    sorted_info.each do |svc|
        puts "     host: #{svc[:host]}"
        puts "   status: #{svc[:status]}"
        puts "           #{svc[:status_message]}"
    end
    puts '-'*40
end
```

You can also save the sorting methods for later use:

```
sort_by_status = Proc.new { |a, b| a[:status] <=> b[:status] }
sorted_info = group_info.sort &sort_by_status
```

Here's the JSON converted to a Ruby hash in case you need it.

```
val = {
    :status => "successful",
    :service_list => [
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [find_all](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) and [sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

```
# Get all the thingies with the service name "web"
thingies.find_all {|thingy| thingy[:service_name] == 'web' }

# Sort all the thingies by status
thingies.sort_by {|thingy| thingy[:status] }

# Put them together
thingies.find_all {|thingy| thingy[:service_name] == 'web' } \
        .sort_by  {|thingy| thingy[:status]}
```

Comment: which would work to a point if the service names weren't dynamic on a system to system basis

Comment: @chris What do you mean? The code I wrote was simply to illustrate the methods themselves. Of course, in the actual application, the service name wouldn't be hard coded, it would come from somewhere else.